# How to scrape a dynamic website with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, dynamic, web-scraping, nokogiri

I want to scrape a React website that has products with names and descriptions. The HTML structure looks like this:

```
<h6 class="menu-index-page__item-title" data-reactid=".5c2v.$menuItemContent.0">
  <span data-reactid=".5c2v.$menuItemContent.0.1">Product name</span>
</h6>
<p class="menu-index-page__item-desc" data-reactid=".5c2v.$menuItemContent.1">
  <span data-reactid=".5c2v.$menuItemContent.1.0">
    <span data-reactid=".5c2v.$menuItemContent.1.0.0">
      <span data-reactid=".5c2v.$menuItemContent.1.0.0.0:$0">Description line 1</span>
      <br data-reactid=".5c2v.$menuItemContent.1.0.0.0:$0br">
    <span data-reactid=".5c2v.$menuItemContent.1.0.0.$1">
      <span data-reactid=".5c2v.$menuItemContent.1.0.0.$1.0">
        <span data-reactid=".5c2v.$menuItemContent.1.0.0.$1.0.0">Description line 2</span>
          <span data-reactid=".5c2v.$menuItemContent.1.0.0.$1.0.1">…</span>
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
```

If the description has more or fewer lines, the number of `span` tags will change, therefore making a XPath search invalid.

The only thing that comes back for each product on each page is:

```
.$menuItemContent.1.0.0.0:$0
```

for the first line of the description and

```
.$menuItemContent.1.0.0.$1.0.0
```

for the second line of the description.

Could I use a regular expression to grab just this part from the `data-reactid` attribute?

I am using Nokogiri at the moment.

Comment: The data is probably either in a big json object on the same page or it's coming from an ajax call. You don't need Nokogiri for this.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need to see a minimal example of what you tried that demonstrates the problem you ask about. Explaining doesn't do any good without code as it takes 10,000 words to replace a piece of code.

Comment: Correctly written XPath expressions can work fine if the site changes.

Answer (score 1):

The prices are more than likely dynamically loaded by a javascript once the webpage has finished displaying.

To be able to scrape dynamically loaded data, you will need to use a library like [Watir](http://watir.com/guides/) which is supported by Rails 5.

With Watir, you are able to wait until all scripts are executed and all data is loaded before attempting to scrape the site.

Comment: hi, how do you wait for the page and data to be loaded?